# Sliding bottom line on hover, color change

Tags: jquery, html, css

When hovering over links, the `color` of the sliding line doesn't change, but I'd like it to match the `color` of the link above. How can I do that?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#example-one").append("<div id='slider'></div>");

  var $slider = $("#slider");

  $slider
    .width($(".current_page").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $slider.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $slider.width());

  $("#example-one div").find("a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();

    $slider.stop().animate({
      left: leftPos,
      width: newWidth
  });
}, function() {
     $slider.stop().animate({
       left: $slider.data("origLeft"),
       width: $slider.data("origWidth")
     });    
   });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arrial Narrow;
  background: #2F2626;
}

#nav { 
  margin: 15px;
}

#example-one { 
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  word-spacing: 15px;
}

#example-one div { 
  display: inline-block;  
}

#example-one a { 
  color: white; 
  font-size: 18px; 
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#slider { 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px; 
  left: 0; 
  height: 1px; 
  background: red;
}

.current_page a { 
  color: red !important; 
}

.blue a:hover { 
  color: blue !important; 
}

.orange a:hover { 
  color: orange !important; 
}

.yellow a:hover { 
  color: yellow !important; 
}

.lime a:hover { 
  color: lime !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav">
  <div id="example-one">
    <div class="current_page"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
    <div class="blue"><a href="#">About</a></div>
    <div class="orange"><a href="#">Service</a></div>
    <div class="yellow"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></div>
    <div class="lime"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use specifc CSS rules as:

```
.yellow:hover ~ #slider {
    background: yellow !important;
}
```

[SEE jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GJQA5/1/)

Comment: Nice! You can also add `transition: background .3s linear;`: http://jsfiddle.net/GJQA5/1/

Answer (score 1):

I like the CSS solution of A.Wolff best, but here's an alternative.

The changes are only made in your jQuery code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#example-one").append("<div id='slider'></div>");

    var $slider = $("#slider");

    $slider
        .width($(".current_page").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page a").position().left)
        .data("origColor", $slider.css("background-color"))
        .data("origLeft", $slider.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $slider.width());

    $("#example-one div").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        elColor = $el.css("color");
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $slider.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        }).css('background-color', $el.css("color"));
    }, function() {
        $slider.stop().animate({
            left: $slider.data("origLeft"),
            width: $slider.data("origWidth")
        }).css('background-color', $slider.data("origColor"));;    
    });
});
```

Check your [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GJQA5/8/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something much more simple: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/GJQA5/7/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#example-one").append("<div id='slider'></div>");

    var $slider = $("#slider");

    $slider
        .width($(".current_page").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $slider.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $slider.width());

    $("#example-one div").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $slider.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
        $slider.css('background', $(this).parent().prop('class'));
    }, function() {
        $slider.stop().animate({
            left: $slider.data("origLeft"),
            width: $slider.data("origWidth")
        });
       $slider.css('background', 'red');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update code:

**new CSS**

```
#slider.blue { 
background-color: blue; 
}

#slider.orange { 
background-color: orange; 
}

#slider.yellow { 
background-color: yellow; 
}

#slider.lime { 
background-color: lime; 
}
```

**JS COde**

```
$(function() {
    $("#example-one").append("<div id='slider'></div>");

    var $slider = $("#slider");

    $slider
        .width($(".current_page").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $slider.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $slider.width());

    $("#example-one div").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $slider.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth,
        }).addClass($(this).parent().attr('class'));
    }, function() {
        $slider.stop().animate({
            left: $slider.data("origLeft"),
            width: $slider.data("origWidth")
        }).removeAttr('class');    
    });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GJQA5/6/)

Answer (score -1):

My approach:

**Working:**

http://jsfiddle.net/skozz/YW24L/1/

**Pro tip:**

You can refactor this code using array + each/for loop.

```
$(function() {
    $("#example-one").append("<div id='slider'></div>");

    var $slider = $("#slider");

    $slider
        .width($(".current_page").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $slider.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $slider.width());

    $("#example-one div").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $slider.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function() {
        $slider.stop().animate({
            left: $slider.data("origLeft"),
            width: $slider.data("origWidth")
        });    
    });

    $('.blue').hover()


        $( ".blue" ).hover(
        function() {
            $( '#slider' ).css( "background", "blue" );
        }
        );

        $( ".orange" ).hover(
        function() {
            $( '#slider' ).css( "background", "orange" );
        }
        );

        $( ".yellow" ).hover(
        function() {
            $( '#slider' ).css( "background", "yellow" );
        }
        );
         $( ".lime" ).hover(
        function() {
            $( '#slider' ).css( "background", "lime" );
        }
        );   
});
```